# Why can't I output it?

Tags: 7, views, theming

```
stdClass Object(
  [nid] => 98
  .......
  [title] => hello world!
  [body] =>
  ........
  [field_img] => Array(
    [0] => Array(
      [fid] => 200
      [list] => 1
      [data] => Array(
        [alt] => 
        [title] => 
      )

      [uid] => 1
      [filename] => coupon.jpg
      [filepath] => sites/default/files/coupon_0.jpg
      [filemime] => image/jpeg
      [filesize] => 4434
      [status] => 1
      [timestamp] => 1302080050
      [nid] => 98
      [view] =>  **the image**
      ......
    )
  )
)
```

Supposing the object is `$test`,  `echo $test->field_img[0]["timestamp"]` in `views-view-fields.tpl.php` outputs `1302080050`, but `echo $test->field_img[0]["nid"]` and `echo $test->field_img[0]["view"]` don't output anything; I can't print 98 and the image. `print_r($test->field_img[0])` doesn't print the node ID and `view`? Why?

Answer (score 3):

In Views template files you have access to the following objects:

- `$row`
- `$fields['field_my_field_value']->row`
- `$fields['field_my_file_value']->content`

You do not have access to multiple image objects in your case. You should call an external function to retrieve data for each item.

```
$arg = (object) array(
  'type' => $fields['type']->raw,
  'vid' => $fields['vid']->raw,
);
$files = filefield_get_node_files($arg);

foreach ($files as $file) {
  print theme('imagecache', 'preview_body', $file['filepath']);
}
```

Comment: how to use  external function to retrieve data for each item.could you make me an example? thank you